# configure HA Proxy to allow some requests certain application servers

Tags: haproxy, cluster

I have a setup with HaProxy where each haproxy server routes traffic to a number of application servers. The routing for normal http traffic is based on a hash of the request url.

Now I want to create some rules to allow certain administrative requests to be routed to specific application servers. That is I have application servers "node06 - node15". I'd like to be able to request node06.mydomain.com/my-admin-request and have that be routed to the correct application server.

I can't do this via dns. All requests come in via a single exposed ip address into the cluster.

So I have made an haproxy config that does what I want:

```
frontend www-http
       bind :80
       reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http

       acl node06 hdr_beg(host) -i node06.
       use_backend node06-status if node06

       acl node07 hdr_beg(host) -i node07.
       use_backend node07-status if node07

       # ... and many more such nodes ...

       default_backend application-backend


       # This is the application back end. 
       # Route request based on hash of url
backend application-backend
       balance url_param url check_post

       server node06 192.168.1.70:80 check
       server node07 192.168.1.71:80 check

       # ... and many more such nodes ...

       # these are the status back ends. This is so we can make requests
       # direct to each node for the status console.
backend node06-status
       server node06 192.168.1.70:80

backend node07-status
       server node07 192.168.1.71:80

       # ... and many more such back ends ...
```

This will work (I think), but its really wordy. I have to create identical blocks of configurations three times for each application server in the cluster. It will become unmanageable if I extend this beyond 10's of nodes.

Is there a way to configure this so that I don't have to separate configuration lines per application server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the ACL and use-server (rather than use-backend) in the backend definition. Also, I think you might be able to use inline ACLs and not necessarily define them before using.

Comment: That works and is much better than what I had.